# Why does pg_dump create a gigantic file?

Tags: postgresql

I am currently trying to back up a postgres 10.x database.  If I check the size of the database using the snippet here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage#Finding_the_largest_databases_in_your_cluster , the database is 180MB.  However, if I use

```
pg_dump my_database > my_database_backup
```

to backup the data, it creates a file over 2GB in size.  Any thoughts on why `pg_dump` would be creating a backup file that is over 10x the size of the raw data? I assume that the inline sql commands might cause some of a file size increase, but 10x seems a bit extreme to me.

Edit: the specific query done to check db size (there are only 2 databases on this server, so it was within the limit 20)

```
SELECT d.datname AS Name,  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) AS Owner,
    CASE WHEN pg_catalog.has_database_privilege(d.datname, 'CONNECT')
        THEN pg_catalog.pg_size_pretty(pg_catalog.pg_database_size(d.datname))
        ELSE 'No Access'
    END AS SIZE
FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN pg_catalog.has_database_privilege(d.datname, 'CONNECT')
        THEN pg_catalog.pg_database_size(d.datname)
        ELSE NULL
    END DESC -- nulls first
    LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Can you post the exact query that you used for size checking ?
Are you sure that the user that you used to check the data size has access to all tables ?

Comment: @Dvorog- I've added the query to the question.

Comment: Do you maybe have many really large text values in the tables? Those would be compressed "inside" the database, but not compressed in a SQL dump. What's the size of a custom dump? `pg_dump -Fc -f my_database_backup -d my_database`